# Coins Change with Greedy algorithm

Tags: java, greedy

Hy guys, for some reason my greedy coins change program does not work. The function should return with the minimum amount of coins you can change a value and there is an array as well which includes the coins you can use for this. My program does not show anything an I dont know why.

```
public class Main {

public static int coinChangeGreedy(int[] coins, int n) {

        int result = 0;

        while (n != 0)
        {

            for (int i=coins.length - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
            {
                if (coins[i] <= n)
                {
                    n = n - coins[i];
                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] coins = {1, 2, 5};
        int n = 11;

        coinChangeGreedy(coins, n);

    }

}
```

Comment: Greedy algorithm is not suitable for this problem, you should use ``dynamic programming`` instead

Comment: It doesn't show anything because you're printing  nothing...

Comment: *as well which includes the coins you can use* - you're also not keeping track of that

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first - you are not printing anything - you just run the function. 
Second - you have a bit of a flaw in your code. You see - if you find a coin that works, you shouldn't go to the next coin, but see if that one "fits" again. 
In your example with `n=11`. You have 5 as the first one and then move to 2. But you should actually try the 5 again (prevent the `for` loop from going to the next element). See the example:

```
public static int coinChangeGreedy(int[] coins, int n) {

        int result = 0;

        while (n != 0) {

            for (int i=coins.length - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
                if (coins[i] <= n) {
                    n = n - coins[i];
                  System.out.println("Adding " +coins[i]);
                  i++; //neutralizing i-- with i++.

                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Not you'll see that 5 is taken twice.  
P.s. - if you are assuming that the coin array will be ascending.
And to print it, you just go:

```
System.out.println("Total coins needed: " +coinChangeGreedy(coins, n));
```

Additionally - if you want to keep track of coins used, you can store them in an `ArrayList` every time it is chosen. list.add(coins[i])`. And of course you declare and initialize that`list` at the beggining.